# Which is the best way of defining functions in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Hi I am writing function in angularjs,I don't no which the best practice to define methods. Please suggest me great appreciate.

**Type1:**

```
var getBranchKey = function(currentBranchName) {

};
```

**Type2:**

```
$scope.getBranchKey = function(currentBranchName) {

};
```

Comment: Well do you need it on the `$scope` or not?

Comment: It depends where are you using it. I you need the function to be accessible from the view, then is the second one. If it's a helper or whatever, then the first

Answer (score 1):

As @Alexander Elgin said, if you need to call the function from the view you have to include it in the `$scope`. But this can be avoided by using `controllerAs` syntax, which I recommend you for many reasons.

You can take a look to an angular styleguide, it will help you to know how people do the things and learn from their experience, for example this [John Papa's guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide).

[Here](https://jsbin.com/cobaba/edit?html,js,output) you have a quick example.